# Try-Catch-Finally Block

Tags: java, exception

i already know that the traditional Try block in java must have at least catch block or finally block (both or either), and i already know that checked exceptions must be handled or declared. 
but i am wondering why it won't compile although i have used correct try block syntax

i have this piece of code here , in the main method i used Try with finally block but i am wondering why it won't compile

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ExHandling {

public void connect() throws IOException
    {
        Socket s = new Socket(); 
        try
        {
            s.getInputStream();
        }
        catch(IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            s.close();
        }
    }
public static void main(String []args)
    {
        ExHandling ex = new ExHandling(); 

        try
        {
            ex.connect();

        }


        finally 
        {
            System.out.println("Finally");
        }

    }
}
```

Any Help Please

Comment: Well your `main` method isn't declared to catch an `IOException` - what do you expect to happen if `ex.connect()` throws `IOException`? The finally block will execute, but the `IOException` should be propagated... which the method signature doesn't indicate.

Comment: connect() doesn't throw (exception is cached) so it shouldn't be declared with `throws`

Comment: Whenever asking about an error (compiler error, runtime error), always quote the **exact** error text.

Comment: @Jezor: Bingo, well-spotted. (BTW, it's "caught", not "cached" -- "cached" makes it sound like they kept it around for later.)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `throws` clause from your `connect()` method. It already catches the `IOException`. If you declare your method as throwing a checked exception it must be caught upon calling.

---

Update: since [Socket#close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close()) can itself throw an exception, **you** need to decide what do you want to do about it. Exception handling is hard because people tend to only think about the happiest path a program can take.

If you don't want to catch the exception explicitly in the `main()` method, you have only one choice: wrap the call to `s.close()` (and every other method that can throw a checked exception) into its' own `try-catch` block and remove the `throws` clause:

```
    public void connect() {
        Socket s = new Socket();
        try {
            s.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                s.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

But you should probably think—"what should I do when it fails?"—each time you're dealing with code that might throw.

Comment: @Berger I was answering from my phone but OH MY GOD YOU'RE RIGHT... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close() I will update my answer shortly

Answer (score 0):

Either catch the thrown `IOException` or throw it and let `JVM` handle the same.

Answer (score 0):

IOException checked exception so you need **catch** or add an exception to a signature method. **final** just guarantee whatever happens final block will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `main` method to catch the `IOException`. If you do so, when the exception is thrown in your `connect()` method, it will be propagated to the `main` method and your finally block will be executed. If that is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

finally itself cannot handle any exception. So when using try{} finally then the code inside try should either not be raising any exception or your method must be throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

It won't compile because just as you indicated, the s.close() in your finally block can throw an IOException and you chose to handle that checked exception by specifying the "throws IOException" clause.  Because of that choice, the calling method must handle that checked exception by either catching it or also specifying it will throw the exception.

It is unclear what results you desire other than it must compile, so here are three options:

1) Wrap s.close with it's own try/catch and remove the throws clause.

2) Move "ExHandling ex" definition inside the caller's try/catch.

3) Add a throws clause to the caller (and remove the try/finally if desired).  **RECOMMENDED**

CAUTION: You really don't want to catch an exception and do "e.printStackTrace();".  All this does is mask issues in your logic.  You should only catch an exception if you plan to handle it in some manner; otherwise, you should allow the exception to propagate up the chain of callers.  Thus, only use options 1 & 2 if you really wish to do something in all the catch clauses.

Option 1: Wrap s.close with it's own try/catch and remove the throws clause.

```
    

    public void connect() {
        Socket s = new Socket();
        try {
            s.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                s.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExHandling ex = new ExHandling();
        try {
            ex.connect();
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("Finally");
        }
    }
```

Option 2: Move "ExHandling ex" definition inside the caller's try/catch.  *In this case I would recommend using try with resources for the socket.*

```
    

    public void connect() throws IOException {
        Socket s = new Socket();
        s.getInputStream();
        s.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ExHandling ex = new ExHandling();
            ex.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("Finally");
        }
    }
```

Option 3: Add a throws clause to the caller (and remove the try/finally if desired).  **RECOMMENDED**

```
    

    public void connect() throws IOException {
        Socket s = new Socket();
        s.getInputStream();
        s.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ExHandling ex = new ExHandling();
        ex.connect();
        System.out.println("Finally");
    }
```